# SPWeb.ProcessBatchData() create strange folder name in sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint

i am using SPWeb.ProcessBatchData() method to batch create folders inside one document library. everything works fine expect after folders have been created, folders all have very strange name. for example if my document library's name is 000, then the folder name's is "1._000". I tried a lot of other properties, but i have no luck to find out how to set the folder name right. Can some one help me on this?

Cheers

Comment: Can you Post the XML you are using for the ProcessBatchData

Comment: Hi Kusek
Here is my xml looks like
"<Method ID=\"{0}\">" +
"<SetList>{1}</SetList>" +
"<SetVar Name=\"Cmd\">Save</SetVar>" +
"<SetVar Name=\"ID\">New</SetVar>" +
"<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#column1\">{2}</SetVar>" +
"<SetVar Name=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office#column2\">{3}</SetVar>" +
"</Method>";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about the webservices are a bit more strict on the characters you can put in and it cannot process the same amount of requests, but you can work around that I guess :)

What you can do though if you really want to use the ProcessBatchData method is, re-use the result you receive back from the method. If it's correct, you will get all the ListItemId's back from each folder. Using the Id's you can create another batch to rename the Title's of the items.

But if I were you, I would switch and use the webservice and workaronud that :)

Answer (score 0):

this is the correct syntax of the XML to create a folder truly titled:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<ows:Batch OnError="Continue">
<Method ID="Test">
<SetList Scope="Request">82d62a9a-55ba-49c8-a9b8-68ec965a5931</SetList>
<SetVar Name="Cmd">Save</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="ID">New</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="Type">1</SetVar>
<SetVar Name="owsfileref">/sites/1/docs/folder1</SetVar>
</Method>
</ows:Batch>
```

the critical line is this one:

```
<SetVar Name="Type">1</SetVar>
```

"Type" is the accepted alias of the FSObjType field

**Regards,
Ahmad**